# How can I create tables on aws dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb

I tried to implement something like this URL. But it's not working.
There is no response.

Who can help me?

This is my code.

```
var dynamo = require('dynamodb');
var Joi = require('joi');

dynamo.AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEYID,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: AWS_REGION,
  endpoint: AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT
});

var Account = dynamo.define('Account', {
  hashKey : 'email',
 
  // add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps : true,
 
  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    name    : Joi.string(),
    age     : Joi.number(),
    roles   : dynamo.types.stringSet(),
    settings : {
      nickname      : Joi.string(),
      acceptedTerms : Joi.boolean().default(false)
    }
  }
});

dynamo.createTables(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error creating tables: ', err);
    res.json({message: 'Create table error'});
  } else {
    console.log('Tables has been created');
    res.json({message: 'Create table success'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you happen to be executing this code within AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a non AWS site. This JavaScript use case, along with many more, is available in the Official AWS Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/dynamodb/ddb_createtable.js

Comment: I checked this code. The reason I to want use "dynamodb" is that I want to make a model(based on MVC logic) for the AWS dynamodb. Have you experience in modeling for AWS dynamodb